# POSIX regex that can recognize escape characters

Tags: regex, posix

I am trying to write a POSIX regex that describes a string in the following form: a '[' character, followed by any number of any character that is not a ']' unless it is immediately preceded by a '*' character, followed by a closing ']' character. Here is an example of the type of string I am trying to be able to catch:

`[dgks8hsb_[(jxx*]9ii]`

The following string should only contain the match `[ojbnb]`:

`[ojbnb]sda]`

The closest regex to the one I need that I have been able to come up with is: `\[[^]]*\]`. I understand why this won't work but I can't seem to extend this idea to create the regex I need.

Comment: POSIX regex is extremely limited in capabilities. I don't believe what you want can be achieved with a strict POSIX regex.

Comment: I did have a feeling that was the case.

Comment: No, it's actually rather easy to do what you want with any modern regex engine, but POSIX regex was developed in ancient times, meant to be backward compatible with ancient tools. Can you be more specific about the exact tool you're using to perform regex with?

Comment: I'm writing a C program. Do you know of a regex library and a regex I could use to catch the pattern in my question?

Answer (score 0):

For matching between the square brackets, use an alternation for either `*]` (via `\*]`) or *not* a `]` (via `[^\]]`):

```
\[(\*]|[^\]])+]
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/rdQewAqGNPxKWo).

Comment: Would this work as a POSIX regex?

Comment: @steph No, but it would require only small changes to be POSIX complaint. Just escape the parenthesis with backslashes, and replace the `+` with both `*` and repeating the subexpression, or just `\{0,\}`. So `\[\(\*]|[^\]]\)\{0,\}]` for example.